# Prediction API in Salesforce Einstein

Tags: einstein

Is there an API in Salesforce Einstain I could use for Prediction. My case:
There are factors **A**, **B**, **C**, **D** influencing factor **X**. I'd like to have an API for getting best **A** and **B** which maximizes X.

Answer (score 1):

Einstein Prediction Builder is apparently still in Pilot, so you can contact your AE or CSR for more details. However, there is indeed an API that allows you to consider multiple inputs for the best output, and EPB is where you'll find it. You'll want to check out the trailheads/documentation/etc for more information.